# Is it possible to create global objects in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net-maui, global-object

When I saw the TabBar and the Flyout menu in .NET Maui I started wondering if its possible to create your own global object for your application.
does anyone know how to do this?

(I want to add a status icon at the corner of my screen without having to manually add it to all pages.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple Floating Button and add it to your pages.
You can create an image with a transparent background in your favorite editor and then assign it a location on the Page.

You can refer to the following code:

```
  <AbsoluteLayout>
     <!--Other components-->
     <ImageButton Source="icon.png" 
            BackgroundColor="Green"
        CornerRadius="80"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".95,.95,80,80" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```