# How to properly inherit a ContentView's features and extend them in a child ContentView in MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have implemented a custom control that represents a start/pause button that is used in several pages of my app. On some other pages, I have this same button but with additional functionalities, like some gauge circle around the button which decreases over time. It is working fine but I want to understand what is ideal for this in terms of architecture.

Here is the XAML of the first custom control:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="StartPauseButton"
                 x:Name="startPauseButton"
                 >
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="startButton"
                    BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference startPauseButton}, Path= BackgroundColor}"
                    TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference startPauseButton}, Path= TextColor}"
                    Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference startPauseButton}, Path= Paused, Converter={local:StartPauseButtonConverter}}"
                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference startPauseButton}, Path= Start}"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                    FontFamily="MaterialIcons" CornerRadius="100" FontSize="60"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentView>
```

And then the second one:

```
    <local:StartPauseButton xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="StartPauseProgressionButton"
                 x:Name="startPauseProgressionButton"
                 >
        <Grid>
            <!-- Here I want to have the UI from the parent ContentView, + the additional UI -->
            <GraphicsView x:Name="ProgressView">
        </Grid>
    </local:StartPauseButton>
```

Now this is not working, as the UI of the second ContentView overrides the UI of the first one so obviously this is not a good approach.

**-> What I would like to know is, based on the use case I described here, what would be a good approach to this ?**

1 Have one single ContentView with all the UI and functionalities of both controls, but having the simpler one simply use what it needs and hide the unused one ?

2 Doing inheritance of some sort, as I am trying to achieve ? 1 single cs file but 2 xaml ? I don't have much experience with XAML but I feel there must be some neat and simple solution I am missing...

I hope I make sense, thanks a lot for any input

Comment: You can check my answer about [How to create reusable Components in .NET MAUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751527/how-to-create-reusable-components-in-net-maui/74779935#74779935).