# What is the right way to declare a custom views with content?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I want to make some custom views, which inherit from each other, and each take some content.

I am relatively new to Maui and tried to implement 2 basic views like this:

MyGenericView.xaml:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestMauiApp.MyGenericView">
    
    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="5">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Frame>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>
```

MyMoreSpecificView.xaml:

```
<local:MyGenericView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     x:Class="TestMauiApp.MyMoreSpecificView"
                     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMauiApp">

    <ContentView>
        <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Frame BackgroundColor="Blue"
                       Padding="5">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Frame>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView>

</local:MyGenericView>
```

and display them like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestMauiApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMauiApp">

    <StackLayout Spacing="5">

        <local:MyGenericView>
            <Label Text="Label inside MyGenericView" />
        </local:MyGenericView>

        <local:MyMoreSpecificView />

        <local:MyMoreSpecificView>
            <Label Text="Label inside MyMoreSpecificView" />
        </local:MyMoreSpecificView>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Which looks like that:

[image]

Which makes sense, since the whole content of the specific view gets overwritten by the Label.

My next attempt was to change `MyMoreSpecificView.xaml` to this:

```
<local:MyGenericView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     x:Class="TestMauiApp.MyMoreSpecificView"
                     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMauiApp">

    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="Blue"
                   Padding="5">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Frame>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>

</local:MyGenericView>
```

Which results in this:

[image]

Which also makes since, as now the content of the generic view get overwritten by the specific view.

What I want is to get a result where the Label is displayed inside the blue frame, which then is inside the red frame.

These attempts above just are the two that made the most sense to me, I tried many other combinations of nested `ControlTemplates`, `ContentViews` and `ContentPresenters` but sadly didn't succeed yet. I feel like creating custom views in Maui is unnecessary complicated in comparison to Android.

Comment: What is your initial problem or what are you trying to achieve in the first place before it got "unnecessary complicated" like you said?

Comment: I am trying to achieve some basic custom views that I can inherit and add some additional content to. I achieved this for one view (MyGenericView), because ContentView provides an option to add a ContentTemplate. But if I want to create another view (MyMoreSpecificView) which basically is just the other view with some additional styling but also takes some content, adding this content becomes complicated

Comment: Did you try to use the  `<local:MyGenericView>
            <Label BackgroundColor="Blue" Text="Label inside MyGenericView" />
        </local:MyGenericView>`? You can change the label color instead of the frame color.

Comment: The views above are just an example. I cannot combine the two views into one, since my actual goal is, to have many other views inherit from MyGenericView.

Comment: You can check this answer about [How to create reusable Components in .NET MAUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751527/how-to-create-reusable-components-in-net-maui/74779935#74779935).